# Troublesome recurrence equation: T(n) = 2*T(ceil((sqrt(n)))+1

Tags: math, recurrence

I have recently encountered a recurrence problem:

> T(n) = 2*T(ceil((sqrt(n)))+1
>
> T(1)=1;

I am unable to see this function terminate at all when I draw my recurrence tree. The general node form in the tree (n<sup>1/2<sup>i</sup></sup>) becomes 1 only when 1/2<sup>i</sup> becomes 0. This means i should tend to infinity.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [Math.SE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right that if sqrt is the ceiling of the square root, then you'll never reach 1 by repeatedly applying square roots. I'm going to assume that you meant to use the floor, which means that you will indeed eventually hit 1 as the recurrence unwinds.

In this case, your recurrence is more properly

> T(1) = 1
>
> T(n) = 2T(⌊√n⌋) + 1

A standard technique for solving recurrences involve square roots is to make a substitution. Let's define a new value k such that n = 2<sup>k</sup>. Notice that √n = (2<sup>k</sup>)<sup>1/2</sup> = 2<sup>k/2</sup>. In other words, taking the square root of n is equivalent to halving the value of k. Because of this, we can convert the above recurrence, which involves square roots, into a new recurrence that will more closely match the form used by the Master Theorem and other recurrence-solving techniques. Specifically, let's define S(k) = T(2<sup>k</sup>). Then we get the recurrence

> S(0) = 1
>
> S(k) = 2S(⌊k / 2⌋) + 1

It's a lot easier to see how to solve this recurrence. Either by recognizing this recurrence from elsewhere or by using the Master Theorem, we get that S(k) = Θ(k). Now, we wanted to solve for T(n), so we can use the fact that S(k) = T(2<sup>k</sup>) = T(n). Since S(k) = Θ(k), we now see that T(n) = Θ(k). Since we chose k such that 2<sup>k</sup> = n, this means that k = lg n. Therefore, T(n) = Θ(log n), so the recurrence works out to Θ(log n).

Hope this helps!